# fosuserbundle: set api key using event listner

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I'm using symfony 2.3 and FosUserBundle ~2.0@dev. I want to set an api key for every user after a success registration. I implemented an event listner for this purpose but it doesn't work. I didn't find where is exactly the problem.
**RegistrationConfirmListener**

```
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

private $router;
private $em;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->router = $router;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess'
    );
}

public function onRegistrationSuccess(\FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent $event) {
    $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
    // génération d'un unique key ,ici on a le id comme prefix donc garantie pas de duplication du key
    $user->setApiKey(md5(uniqid($user->getId(), TRUE)));
    $url = $this->router->generate('biginfo_admin_homepage');
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}

}
```

**service.yml**

```
services:            
biginfo_user.registration_complet:
    class: Biginfo\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
    arguments: [@router,@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

Comment: Probably you forgot to call $this->em->flush() method after setting api key.

Comment: I tried to add $this->em->flush() and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event. Because REGISTRATION_COMPLETED event listener method receives a FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent instance, which is not fit for your situation.

Comment: Please try to remove dump($user); from your code. There is no dump function in SPL. There is no other errors, your code should work like a charm.

Comment: I did remove dump($user) but still the same problem